# ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC sort first char

Tags: android, sql

I created a CursorLoader like this

```
String mSelection = NAME + " IS NOT NULL AND " + excludeSim;
String mOrder = NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    
CursorLoader cl = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), CONTENT, null, mSelection, null,
            mOrder);
```

I got a problem with sort name start with diacritycs, with thay CursorLoader I receive result like this

> Laura
>
> Łucja
>
> Lukrecja

I want to get result like

> Laura
>
> Lukrecja
>
> Łucja

Comment: Have you tried using `ORDER BY column_name COLLATE UNICODE`?

Comment: @Ziem then is even worse, uppercase name go as first lowercase go as second ex. Ala, Max, albert

Comment: Try to use [setLocale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29) and then `COLLATE LOCALIZED`.